# How do i set values to Textviews,edittext or charts in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Before i begin,let me say that i've already checked all the links regarding this and the inflater init method doesn't work for me unfortunately

Fragment.java

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater1, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.tab, container, false);
    context = getActivity();
    findViews(view);
    setBar();
    setPie();
    return view;//inflater1.inflate(R.layout.tab, container, false);

}

 private void findViews(View view) {
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    root=(ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.root);
   piechart= (PieChart)view.findViewById(R.id.pie_chart);
    barChart = (BarChart)view.findViewById(R.id.barchart);
    popupContentView=inflater.inflate(popupdashboard,root,false);
```

Activity.java

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard2);
    //Initializing viewPager
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Dashboard"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Transaction Details"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Your Tab Title2"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.simpleViewPager);
    //Creating our pager adapter
    pager adapter = new pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   /// if (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()==0){
        init = new Tab1();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.linearLayout, init);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: send your error log(logcat)

Comment: there's no error @ShashankVerma,it just doesn't show any values

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

1. Create a variable of the type `ViewGroup` locally to the function `onCreate`, then initialize it.

   ```
   ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nameoflayout, container, false);
   ```
2. Then, you could set you TextView using this:

   ```
   TextView txtView = (TextView)root.findViewByID(R.id.nameoftextviewid);
   ```
3. Return variable `root`.

This is exactly what I'm doing in my projects.

Comment: that's what i did,check my fragment class

Comment: @John ok  post your log.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this....**

```
  ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.nameoflayout, container, false);

        piechart= (PieChart)view.findViewById(R.id.pie_chart);
        barChart = (BarChart)view.findViewById(R.id.barchart);

     return view;
```

refrence link..[refer](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Comment: that's what i did,check my fragment class